# Android - EditText hint not updating in soft keyboard screen

Tags: android-edittext, hint

[image]

The hint for my EditText when the soft keyboard is full screen mode is not reflecting the correct value after assigning a new value for hint to the EditText. Please see gif above.

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Below is isolated code to recreate this issue:

#### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding mBinding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(mBinding.getRoot());
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v) {
        mBinding.barcodeEdittext.setHint("Some other Hint");
    }

}
```

#### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/barcode_edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Initial Hint" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Change Hint!"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick" />

</LinearLayout>
```